# I can't get Youtube API To Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I want the player to stop when the the div (.closed) is clicked but it' not woroking. Can someone see where I've gone wrong?

Ive added in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

I've got this in my jQuery

```
closed.click(function () {
        player.stopVideo();                
        movie.delay(1000).animate({
            bottom: -500
        }, {
            duration: 1000
        });
    });
```

** This also messes with the animation*

and this in my code.

```
 <div id="movieContainer"> 
        <div id="movie">
             <iframe id="player" width="644" height="410" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VG9AGf66tXM?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <div class="close"></div>
        </div><!--End of Movie -->
    </div><!-- End of movieContainer -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you get the reference to player? It should be something like this:

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
player.stopVideo();
```